# IEnumerable<Object> which contains an int type that I wish to put in between parenthesis

Tags: c#, sql, string, list, linq

I am trying to create a Temp table in the DB in order to `INNER JOIN` it to another table.

I have a method that gets an `IEnumerable<Object>` as a parameter. 
By using `LINQ` and `String.Join()` I am able to put a string in between each value I need for example `String.Join("), ", SapMaterialIDs.Select(id => id.SapMaterialId)`
this creates a string that looks like 
`1),2),3),...` However I need the leading parenthesis `'('` I am trying to come up with a solution that doesn't make me do extra stuff in my code. for example I could do a `List<string> list = str.Split("),").ToList()` and do a loop that adds the leading `(` to every value but I am definitely not a fan of this approach.

---

Also I am fairly new to asking questions here, so any tips are greatly appreciated. 
Thank you

> Note that I don't want to use a SQL statement that uses the IN(...); therefore I am trying to create a Temp table and use it to JOIN, but I need my string in (#), (#), format.

Comment: Hi @jonnhynick can you post the complete code? it's easier to help with more context.

Comment: Yes next time I will; however, my question has been answered, but thank you much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply do this?

```
String.Join(", ", SapMaterialIDs.Select(id => id.SapMaterialId.ToString("(#)"))
```

BTW, next time, clearly specify what you have and what you need. For example, "I have an array of int and I need them in a string like `(1), (2), (3), ...`. :)

I am not sure how the DB or the joins have anything to do with this, but if you give more context, there might be a simpler way to do what you need.

Comment: I could be wrong but I believed I just did. (Green mark on the answer) again, thank you ! I spent quite some time reading C# in a nutshell until I decided to post.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this that will work with all types (not just numbers) is to simply include the opening and closing parenthesis in your `Join` as well as on both sides of the `Join`:

```
var result = $"({string.Join("), (", SapMaterialIDs.Select(id => id.SapMaterialId))})";
```

As @andrew mentioned in the comments, the above method requires C#6 because it's using [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated). If you're on an older version, you can use concatenation instead:

```
var result = "(" + string.Join("), (", SapMaterialIDs.Select(id => id.SapMaterialId)) + ")";
```

As @cwharris mentioned in the comments, this will return `"()"` if the `Select` statement returns zero results. To resolve this, you can add a `Replace` method to the end to remove them:

```
var result = $"({string.Join("), (", SapMaterialIDs.Select(id => id.SapMaterialId))})"
    .Replace("()", "");
```

Comment: Nice option, although maybe a little harder to read. Just for the record, this requires C♯ 6 (VS2015+).

Comment: @Andrew True, string interpolation requires c#6. Added the concatenation version as well...

Comment: This assumes the length is greater than zero. For zero, the result would be `()`